# Getting a snapshot on the first day of the each month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, calendar

My dataset looks like this:

```
emplid region location sub_dept dept start_dt end_dt     days
------ ------ -------- -------- ---- -------- ---------- ----
123456 East   NY       A           1 7/1/2005 9/30/2005    91
123456 East   NY       B           1 7/1/2012 11/9/2012   131
123456 West   San Jose C           2 7/1/2013 12/31/2013  183
123457 East   NY       B           1 7/1/2017 9/7/2017     68
123457 East   NY       B           1 7/1/2005 12/31/2005  183
123458 East   NY       B           1 7/1/2017 9/7/2017     68
123458 West   San Jose C           2 7/1/2010 7/31/2010    30
123459 East   NY       A           1 7/1/2017 9/7/2017     68
123460 East   Boston   F           3 7/1/2007 11/30/2007  152
```

I need to be able to get a snapshot for each 1st of the month starting from the minimum date. So in the example minimum date is `9/30/2005`. So I need to know in which `department/sub_dept/location/region` was each empl on `10/1/2005, 11/1/2005 , 12/1/2005` all the way through the max date.

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result? (As formatted text, proper columns.)

Comment: Expected result is all the above columns plus 1st_day column with 1st day of each month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention the name of the employee table, so I've called it employee_table. The following query (or something very close to it) should generate what you want:

```
With report_limits as (
      Select Trunc(min(start_dt), 'MONTH') as min_rpt_dt, 
             Trunc(max(end_dt), 'MONTH') as max_rpt_dt 
        From employee_table),
     report_dates as (
      Select add_months(min_rpt_dt, level-1) as rpt_dt
        From report_limits 
     Connect By add_months(min_rpt_dt, level-1) <= max_rpt_dt)
--
Select e.emplid, e.region, e.location, e.sub_dept, e.dept,
       e.start_dt, e.end_dt, e.days, r.rpt_dt
From report_dates r
Inner Join employee_table e on r.rpt_dt Between e.start_dt And e.end_dt
Order By r.rpt_dt, e.emplid;
```

The report_limits query determines the range of report dates, the report_dates query uses a Connect By clause to generate a set of dates within the range, and the main query joins the list of dates to the employee date.

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
 Declare @StartDate date='2005-09-29',
 @EndDate date='2017-04-01'

Select *,
Dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm, 0, date), 0) AS FirstDateOfMonth  from TableName
where   date >=@StartDate and date<=@EndDate
```